# Два глагола подряд

Tags: пунктуация

Фраза из КВН: "Скучно тут у вас. Пойду(,) в плен схожу". А нужна ли запятая после "пойду"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нет, не нужна. "Схожу" - это, по-моему, не сказуемое (так как "пойду" - глагол движения), поэтому не однородное слову "пойду", это обстоятельство "пойду (с какой целью?) схожу".  Таких конструкций много в русском языке: пойду посмотрю, пойду посуду помою, сходи принеси и т.п.

Comment: Не соглашусь на 100%. "Я (*что сделаю?*) пойду." Вполне стандартный вопрос сказуемого. А здесь сказуемое будет "пойду схожу" (ср. "пойду и схожу"). Другой вопрос, что такие конструкции более характерны для разговорной речи...

Comment: Извините, это действительно я ошибся. Я спутал с правилом для инфинитивов. "Пойду схожу" - это неделимое синтаксическое целое, поэтому его нельзя разделять запятой.

Answer (score 0):

Нет, не нужна.
Насколько понимаю, "пойду" здесь своего рода модальный глагол, означающий намеренье. Конечно, модельность его весьма условна, ибо последующий глагол не теряет категории лица, но это другой разговор. Суть в том, что "пойду схожу" неделимое сказуемое.
Впрочем, грамматически возможна и трактовка с двумя однородными сказуемыми, но здесь она по смыслу не подходит.