# Почему не ставится запятая?

Tags: пунктуация, грамматика, запятые

Почему в стихотворении "Радуга"

> Я на радугу-дугу
>   Полюбуюсь побегу

не ставится запятая?
Мне просто интересно.

Comment: Благинина, Елена Александровна. Радуга. 
Я на радугу-дугу// Полюбуюсь побегу -// Семицветную-цветную// На лугу подстерегу.

Answer (score 6):

*Полюбуюсь побегу* - не однородные сказуемые (тогда была бы запятая), а одно составное (одно действие) — побегу полюбоваться.

Похожий вопрос:
[Два глагола подряд | Русский язык](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/7436/%D0%94%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B4)

Интересное обсуждение:
[Как называется явление, когда два глагола стоят рядом в одной форме | Russian Language Stack Exchange](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/14472/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D1%8F%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B0-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8F%D1%82-%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%B2-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B5)

Ответ Грамоты.ру:

> [Вопрос № 277430](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=277430)
>   Какова пунктуация в предложениях типа:
>    "Иди, убери мусор". Нужна ли запятая?
>   **Ответ справочной службы русского языка**
>   Не ставится запятая между двумя глаголами в одинаковой форме, указывающими на движение и его цель или образующими единое смысловое целое (в таких сочетаниях нет однородных членов): Иди убери мусор.

Answer (score -4):

Я бы здесь запятую сохранил.
Хотя тут надо автора спрашивать, что он имел в виду.

Да, есть правило о едином смысловом сочетании двух глаголов, **первый** из которых обозначает движение (много реже - другое действие), а **второй** - цель такого действия.

Но в такой паре невозможна инверсия: "полюбуюсь побегу" совершенно не воспринимается как "побегу полюбуюсь". А следовательно, глаголы тут скорее всего - однородные члены.

Беда, правда, в том, что при трактовке как однородных смысл тоже не слишком проясняется.

Может там дефис поставить, а?!

Comment: В поэтическом тексте инверсия возможна.

Comment: @Людмила *В поэтическом тексте инверсия возможна* - не здесь. Теряется смысл. "Дуб сломал забор" - "Забор сломал дуб".

Comment: Мне кажется, "полюбуюсь побегу" таки да :)) воспринимается как "побегу полюбуюсь". И я отношусь к этому как к допустимой в поэзии вольности, которая не меняет сути дела.