# Почему в этих трёх примерах не ставятся запятые?

Tags: запятые

Объясните, пожалуйста, почему в этих трёх примерах не ставятся запятые:

*Я хочу пойти поговорить*

*У меня нет цели становиться космонавтом*

*Пойдём покушаем*

Comment: См ответы на вопросы: 
Почему не ставится запятая? (https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/439968/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%8f%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%8f/439970#439970)

Comment: Два глагола подряд (https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/7436/%d0%94%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d0%b3%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d1%80%d1%8f%d0%b4)

Comment: Два идущих подряд глагола (https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/21795/%d0%94%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d0%b8%d0%b4%d1%83%d1%89%d0%b8%d1%85-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d1%80%d1%8f%d0%b4-%d0%b3%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b0)

Comment: @Третийглаз А где Вы хотели поставить запятую во втором предложении? Я такого места не нахожу.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Запятые не ставятся, потому что там **нет однородных членов**, одинаковые глагольные формы выполняют разную грамматическую функцию.

1) **Я хочу пойти** (с какой целью?) **поговорить.**

Простое предложение, составное глагольное сказуемое ***хочу пойти.*** Первый инфинитив входит в сказуемое, второй инфинитив является обстоятельством цели.

2) **У меня нет цели** (какой?) **становиться космонавтом.** Инфинитив в роли несогласованного определения. Сравнить: **У меня нет такой цели – становиться космонавтом** (инфинитив обособляется со значением пояснения).

3) **Пойдём покушаем.** Это осложненное простое сказуемое, состоящее из двух глаголов в личной форме. Первый глагол обычно имеет значение положения или движения (сижу читаю, пойду посмотрю)